# How to specify LD_LIBRARY_PATH using subprocess in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am trying to specify LD_LIBRARY_PATH before the executable name while using subprocess in python3 but getting an error specified next.

Can you explain what is wrong? I just want to pass LD_LIBRARY_PATH before the exe name having multiple key-value pair arguments as shown.

```
   myFile = "/home/user1/file1.txt"
   output_path="/usr/local/dir1/dir2/bin/myExe"
   
   if os.name != 'nt':
        libpath = "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=" + os.path.dirname(output_path)
        output_path = libpath + " " + output_path;

    print("\n Output path is '{}'".format(output_path))
    
    opt1 = ['--input', myFile]
    child = subprocess.Popen([output_path, "--header", *opt1,
                                                      '--opt2', 'one' '--opt2', 'two'],
                                                     shell=False, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    # output bytes
    output = child.communicate()[0]
    # exit code
    rc = child.returncode
```

Error given is as below

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/dir1/dir2/bin /usr/local/dir1/dir2/bin/myExe': 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/dir1/dir2/bin /usr/local/dir1/dir2/bin/myExe'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to use the POSIX shell syntax for specifying environment variables when invoking a command, but you are explicitly telling Python *not* to invoke a shell (which is good, since using `shell=True` leads to non-portable code, and is unnecessary here). Incidentally, `shell=False` is the default so you don’t need to specify it.

To specify environment variables for [`Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), pass them as a mapping to the `env` parameter. Be sure to include *all* environment variables though, not just the ones you want to change:

```
output_path = '/usr/local/dir1/dir2/bin/myExe'

env = os.environ.copy()
env.update(LD_LIBRARY_PATH = os.path.dirname(output_path))

child = subprocess.Popen(
    [output_path, '--header', *opt1, '--opt2', 'one' '--opt2', 'two'],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
    env=env
)
```